# Performance difference between pattern matching and if-else

Tags: performance, pattern-matching, ocaml

Why can OCaml generate efficient machine code for pattern matching and not for if-else tests?

I was reading Real World OCaml and I came across [this](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/lists-and-patterns.html#performance) section where they compared the performance of pattern matching to the performance of if-else tests. It turned out that pattern matching in their example was significantly faster than if-else tests. Even though the code doesn't utilize any special pattern match cases that would not be possible with if-else tests, it just compares integers.

They ascribe compiler optimization for pattern matching as the reason for the performance difference. The compiler would be able to generate machine code that jumps directly ot the matched case based on an efficiently chosen set of runtime checks.

I understand this, but I don't really see why the compiler isn't able to do the same thing for the if-else tests. After all, the code is just comparing integers to integers. Is this because OCaml hasn't (yet) optimized if-else tests, or is it because it's impossible to optimize if-else tests like it's possible with pattern matching?

The pattern matching code looks like this:

```
let plus_one_match x =
    match x with
    | 0 -> 1
    | 1 -> 2
    | 2 -> 3
    | _ -> x + 1
```

The if-else code looks like this:

```
let plus_one_if x =
    if      x = 0 then 1
    else if x = 1 then 2
    else if x = 2 then 3
    else x + 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`match` and `if` has different semantics: `match` is parallel, `if` is strictly sequential. If you have expression:

```
 match expr with
 | A -> e1
 | B -> e2
 | C -> e3
 | ...
```

Then it may compare branches in any order. In the example, I provided, it may compile to a binary search, utilizing the fact, that constructors are represented as an oridinary numbers.

In the expression

```
if e1 then e2 else if e3 then e4 else ...
```

it is required by semantics of the language, that `e3` is evaluated strictly after `e1` and iff `e1` is evaluated to false. That means, that compiler can't rearrange the order of comparisons since it can't know whether `e1` is `true` of `false` (and if it knows, then with if expression will be pruned with constant folding, so it doesn't matter).

Back to your example. If you compile your match function you will get, the following code (on x86_64):

```
.L104:
    cmpq    $5, %rax
    jbe .L103
    addq    $2, %rax
    ret
.L103:
    sarq    $1, %rax
    cmpq    $1, %rax
    je  .L101
    jg  .L100
.L102:
    movq    $3, %rax
    ret
.L101:
    movq    $5, %rax
    ret
.L100:
    movq    $7, %rax
    ret
```

That actually corresponds to expression:

```
if x > 2 then x + 1 
else match compare x 1 with 
| 0 -> 2
| 1 -> 3
| _ -> 1
```

Quite efficient code, that uses only two comparisons at all. And in runtime it will usually (depending on data distribution) finish with one comparison.

If you compile an example with `if` then it will emit the code, that basically equal to the original OCaml code. Because, compiler is required to do so, by the semantics of the `if` expression. `if` expression *must* be sequential.

One can argue, that the `if` example, can be compiled to the same code, given that the comparison function is a builtin comparison function. But for that, compiler need to proof, that the comparison function is the builtin or doesn't have side-effects. In that only for one particular case with `int`. I doubt, that someone will write such optimization, because it doesn't worth.

Other distinguishing  feature of a `match` expression, is that matching can be performed on a very restricted set of objects, that share one thing in common, they are all ordinal numbers, or can be ordered. In `if` expressions, we have arbitrary expression.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, it is possible to optimise the if-else test the same way. For example, you could write a new optimiser that works in 2 stages: first transform all if-else tests to pattern matching where possible (still in OCaml) and then run the existing compiler.

Therefore, the answer must be that optimising if-else tests the same way isn't high on the priority list of the compiler developers.

As a future release of the compiler may bring an even better optimisation for the if-else test, I would only change time-critical code now.

Comment: To do this optimization, you need to proof, that `=` function doesn't have side effects. Even builtin `=` has side effect: it raises exception. Of course, one can hardcode in the optimizer a heuristics, that will assume, that for integers it will never throw exceptions. But what about other types? But I doubt, that its worth it.