# Why use pattern matching in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

Let's consider this small function

```
let f x =
     match x with
         0 -> 1 |
         _ -> x ;;
```

This is logically equivalent to

```
let f x = 
   if x = 0 then 1 else x ;;
```

What's then the purpose of pattern matching if we can achieve the same using if/else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually pattern matching allows a compiler to apply more aggressive optimization techniques. In the if/then/else expression the condition is an arbitrary expression, that can contain side effects. For example, the equality operator may do anything, so the compiler cannot, in general, rely that `x=0` means that x is equal to zero. In pattern matching clauses are always constants, and matching means syntactic equality, that cannot be overloaded, so it can be easily compiled directly to assembly comparison operation. In the example with `if`, comparison will be in general compiled to a function call (but afaik in this case the compiler is clever enough, and the generated code would be the same).

But the main difference between if/then/else and pattern matching is that the latter is run in parallel and compiles into binary search trees embedded into the assembly, when if/then/else is just a linear sequence of comparisons (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914230/performance-difference-between-pattern-matching-and-if-else/30939301#30939301) for more information).

### Update

To satisfy OP curiosity I added some assembly output. It is not required to understand x86 assembler, one can just compare a number of instructions, to get a basic idea. You will see.

As I predicted, indeed, compiler emitted nearly the same code, that has the same performance for you example:

Function `with_match` has compiled into efficient code (notice that `0` in OCaml parlance is `1`)

```
with_match:
.L101:
    cmpq    $1, %rax
    je  .L100
    ret
.L100:
    movq    $3, %rax
    ret
```

For function `with_if` compiler also emitted optimal code. The only difference is that in `with_if` function, the condition in jump instruction is inverted.

```
with_if:
.L103:
    cmpq    $1, %rax
    jne .L102
    movq    $3, %rax
    ret
.L102:
    ret
```

This was possible, because compiler uses a trick, that allows him to treat 
`=` as a special function, with some theory attached to it. But in general this is not possible, as `=` can be arbitrary function. We can easily confuse compiler, by adding the following line to the start of the file:

```
let (=) x y = x = y
```

Now all tricks are disabled, and compiler emits this inefficient code.

```
with_if:
    subq    $8, %rsp
.L105:
    movq    %rax, 0(%rsp)
    movq    $1, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    _caml_equal, %rax
    call    _caml_c_call
.L106:
    movq    _caml_young_ptr, %r11
    movq    (%r11), %r15
    cmpq    $1, %rax
    je  .L104
    movq    $3, %rax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
.L104:
    movq    0(%rsp), %rax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

With all that said, I would like to stress, that one shouldn't prefer match over if or vice verse. A construct that is more clean and results in more readable code should be chosen. And ocaml compiler is rather good, and will emit efficient code for you.

I personally lean to more to matches, because this reflects my way of thinking. It is harder for me to reason in terms of if/then/else constructs, and whenever I read them, I mentally translate them into match with clauses. But this is my personal issue. Feel free to use whatever construct, that suits you better.

Comment: Note, however, that guards can cause side effects.

Comment: @antron: What are guards? Are they the same thing as in C++? (`#ifdef MYHEADER_H ... #endif`)

Comment: I'd like to prove it experimentally. :) Will compiling this (and an analogical file for the other variant): http://paste.ubuntu.com/12817123/ , and running `time ./exec` be a reliable benchmark?

Comment: no, it will not. A better way would be to look at assembly and compare a number of instructions. But I bet, that for your particular example, the compiler would be clever wnough to produce identical code, since it use some heuristics.

Comment: @marmistrz: it's this: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec122. Guards aren't part of patterns, but, as you can see, you can use them to put arbitrary conditions on `match` cases, including conditions whose evaluation causes side effects.

Answer (score 3):

In your precise example, a pattern matching does not bring a lot, because you have only 2 cases, and more importantly because your pattern does not have any variable. Just write this example with if/then/else, you will understand:

```
let rec map f = function
    [] -> []
  | a::l -> let r = f a in r :: map f l
```

Note also that pattern matching warns you if you have redundant cases or if you forgot some cases.

Answer (score 2):

A partial pattern matching is detected :

```
type number = Zero | One | Two;

let f= function
    Zero -> 0
  | One  -> 1 ;;

Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
Two
val f : number -> int = <fun>
```